# How does sudo and become in ansible work together?

Tags: ansible

```
- name: "read env"
  shell: "sudo env"
  become: true
```

I have above snippet in Ansible, I want to know the behaviour of using become and sudo together. I am aware become's default action is to turn the action as sudo. In that case will my sudo in the beginning of shell command get nullified ?
I am getting a different results with shell: "sudo env" and shell: "env" when become is set to true/yes

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to add `sudo` to your commands when you are using `become: true`. You can checkout `become_method` from documentation. It will append sudo for you when you use `become: true`.

I highly recommend to read documentation for privilege escalation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html

**UPDATE**

I did misunderstood your question sorry. The default `become_method` is [sudo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/ansible.cfg) in `ansible.cfg`. When you set `become: true` without specifying `become_method` it will basically add a `sudo` prefix to your `cmd`. Here i created a example:

```yaml
# privilege_escalation.yaml
---
- name: privilege escalation
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: command without any escalation
      shell: env

    - name: command with sudo
      shell: sudo env

    - name: command with become and sudo
      shell: sudo env
      become: yes
```

You can run example with this command:

```sh
ansible-playbook -vvv --ask-become-pass  privilege_escalation.yaml
```

1. The first task will run `env`. In the results you can see `USER=your_user` line that represents [current user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76354/who-sets-user-and-username-environment-variables/76356).
2. When you use `sudo` in command, second task will run `sudo env`. In the results you can see `USER=root` and 
   `SUDO_USER=your_user`. This means you escalated your privileges to become `root` when running `env` command. [SUDO_USER](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) environment variable represents the user who invoked sudo.
3. The last task will run `sudo sudo env`. In the results you can see `USER=root` and 
   `SUDO_USER=root`. This means the first you become `root` user, after that `root` user executed `sudo env` command.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @ dorukerenaktas I am aware of what become and become_method does. I was just curious on how it would work when become and sudo used together. I am getting a different results with shell: "sudo env" and shell: "env" when become is set to true/yes

Comment: @NandeeshBijoor i updated the answer, you can check it. If there is anything else i can help please tell me.